# Left outer join query (i think)

Tags: join, left-join

I have two tables that look like this:

Products: `id` `category` `name` `description` `active`

Sales_sheets: `id` `product_id` `link`

`product_id` is a foreign key from the products `id` table

I wrote a prepared statement JOIN like this which works:

```
SELECT p.name, p.description, s.link FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN sales_sheets AS s ON p.id = s.product_id WHERE active=1 AND category=?
```

Basically a product can have a link to a PDF, but not every product will have a sales sheet. So if i try to bring up a product which doesn't have a sales sheet attached to it then it always returns no rows.

So i thought I'd have to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN in place of the INNER JOIN, but that returns no rows too, am I naming the tables in the wrong order? I've never had to use an OUTER join before?

Comment: Why not post the query that didn't work? Looks like a left outer join is what's needed here to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name, p.description, s.link FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sales_sheets s ON p.id = s.product_id
WHERE active = 1 && category = ?
```

Comment: Yes LEFT OUTER JOIN was ok, it was my fault for missing something out of my DB. Apologies.